# aws fargate and private container repository

Tags: aws-fargate

Does AWS Fargate support pulling images from private container registry yet?

As of now, I'm pushing all the images up to dkr.ecr and can't find any documentation around support for private repos.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as of September 10, 2018. The key is to store your private registry credentials in AWS Secrets Manager and provide the ARN as a container level parameter while registering your task definition.

> You can now authenticate container images from any private registry to
>   run task with AWS Fargate.
>
> Previously, if you wanted to run Amazon Elastic Container Service
>   (Amazon ECS) tasks that used images from a private registry, you were
>   restricted to the EC2 launch type configuration. This is because with
>   EC2 launch type, you could authenticate the underlying instance to a
>   private registry by modifying your instance's environment variables.
>   Since Fargate allows you to run containers without having to manage
>   underlying EC2 instances, you couldn’t authenticate these instances to
>   any private registry except Amazon Elastic Container Registry (Amazon
>   ECR).
>
> Now, you can use any private registry of your choice with Fargate or
>   EC2 launch types. You will first store your private registry
>   credentials in AWS Secrets Manager. You will then provide the
>   secret-manager ARN or the secret name as container level parameter
>   while registering your task definition. To learn more about how you
>   can use private registries with AWS Fargate, read our documentation or
>   check out our blog.
>
> Please visit the AWS region table to see all AWS regions where AWS
>   Fargate is available.

[AWS Fargate Now Supports Private Registry Authentication](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/09/aws-fargate-now-supports-private-registry-authentication/)

Comment: Is there any issue in ecs fargate to pull secret value from secret manager?

Comment: @NIravModi - Create a new question with details on what you are asking.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61265108/aws-ecs-fargate-resourceinitializationerror-unable-to-pull-secrets-or-registry