# ResourceInitializationError with AWS ECS deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am deploying containers on ECS (fargate) with platform versions 1.4.0 (Latest) in the private subnet using GitHub action. I have routed the traffic through the NAT gateway and have the ECS task Execution role with the secret manager's full access policy. When I bind ECS service to only one private subnet then the containers getting deployed over ECS with no error, but once I bind two private subnets for making ECS service more available then the task gets stopped with an error below error.

```
ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: unable to retrieve secret from asm: service call has been retried 5 time(s): failed to fetch secret arn:aws:secretsmanager:ap-south-1:27XXXXX...
```

I have tried every possible solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61265108/aws-ecs-fargate-resourceinitializationerror-unable-to-pull-secrets-or-registry) but none is worked for me.

Comment: One of your subnets has to be configured incorrectly. You need to make sure both subnets have a route to the NAT Gateway.

Comment: Or you have a secrets manager vpc endpoint present, but it's in place for only one of your private subnets.