# CannotPullContainerError: pull image manifest has been retried 5 time(s): failed to resolve ref [IMAGE PATH] failed to do request: i/o timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, timeout, aws-fargate, aws-batch

I cannot figure out how to run AWS Batch via Fargate platform.  All I'm trying to do is a hello world echo and write the file to S3.

I'm getting the following error:

```
CannotPullContainerError: pull image manifest has been retried 5 time(s): failed to resolve ref public.ecr.aws/amazonlinux/amazonlinux:latest: failed to do request: Head "https://public.ecr.aws/v2/amazonlinux/amazonlinux/manifests/latest": dial tcp [ID]: i/o timeout
```

Here's my job definition that I registered:

```
{
  "jobDefinitionName": "fargate-hello-world",
  "type": "container",
  "containerProperties": {
    "image": "public.ecr.aws/amazonlinux/amazonlinux:latest",
    "command": [
      "echo",
      "Hello world",
      "|",
      "aws",
      "s3",
      "cp",
      "-",
      "s3://[BUCKET-NAME]/test.txt"
    ],
    "jobRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::[ID]:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::[ID]:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "resourceRequirements": [
      {
        "value": "2.0",
        "type": "VCPU"
      },
      {
        "value": "4096",
        "type": "MEMORY"
      }
    ]
  },
  "platformCapabilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ]
}
```

I've removed some of the details and replaced with `[ID]` and `[BUCKET-NAME]`.

- Is this a permissions/policy issue?
- Is this an issue with my job definition?
- If not, what could this be?

I've also tried with just using `amazonlinux:latest` as the container path and the full dockerhub tag `docker.io/amazonlinux:latest`

I thought this would fix it but apparently not:
[AWS Batch Timeout connecting to ECR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72645571/aws-batch-timeout-connecting-to-ecr)

Any help to get me going in the right direction would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

It sounds like you are either deploying the Fargate task into a private subnet that does not have access to the Internet, or you are deploying to a public subnet but you have the `assignPublicIp` setting set to `false`. In either scenario, the Fargate task can't reach anything outside of the VPC, so it can't connect to any image registry such as DockerHub or ECR.

If you are deploying to a private subnet, you need to add a NAT Gateway to your VPC in a public subnet, and a route to the NAT Gateway in your private subnet's route table.

If you are deploying to a public subnet, you need to set `assignPublicIp` to `true`.

Comment: I used the default settings when creating a fargate compute environment which I believe is a private subnet. What's the best way to set up a public subnet?

Comment: I'm not sure what default settings you are talking about. If you are talking about your AWS account's default VPC, then it will have a public subnet in it already. That's the only "default" network you get in AWS.

Comment: I was trying out AWS Batch, didn't pay much attention to all the settings, forgot to enable this setting in the UI: `Assign public IP` which maps to `assignPublicIp` in the JSON view. Hope this helps.

Comment: how about internet gateway?

Comment: @DaveAnkin a public subnet is a subnet with a route to an Internet Gateway. If you have a specific question, I suggest posting it as a separate question on this site.