# i am not able to create wikijs service using AWS farget. Getting this error

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

```
Task stopped at: 2023-09-07T07:38:26.182Z
ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: 
unable to retrieve ecr registry auth: service call has been retried 3 time(s): RequestError: send request failed caused by: Post "https://api.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/": 
dial tcp 13.234.9.96:443: i/o timeout. 
Please check your task network configuration.
```

I follow steps from this documentation https://docs.requarks.io/install/awsecs and used same image as mentioned in documentation but got this error while pulling image so i pushed this image to ECR and put ECR uri in url section but still got same error.

```
Environmental Variables
Key Type    Value
DB_TYPE Value   postgres
DB_SSL  Value   false
DB_PORT Value   5432
DB_HOST Value   aws db url
DB_NAME Value   wikijs
DB_USER Value   postgres
DB_PASS Value   db password
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61530223/92837 either create a VPC Endpoint, add a NAT gateway or run the fargate task in a public subnet. It seems like you're running it in a private subnet and Fargate cannot pull the image

Comment: we tried same but could not succed we even try create this service in default vpc and public subnet and push the image in ecr and use ecr image url while creating a service but still facing same issue.